# How to get JSON data from POST request using Servlet

Tags: java, jquery, json, servlets

This is my code on the client side:

```
 $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    charset:'utf-8',
                    url:'http://localhost:8180/GisProject/MainService',
                    data:JSON.stringify(params),
                    success:function(msg)
                    {
                        console.log(msg);
                    },
                    error:function(xhr,status)
                    {
                        console.log(status);
                    },      
                    contentType:"application/json"  
            });
```

I have previously parsed this data in Node using `express.bodyParser` but now I have to parse it using the `servlet`.I have seen people assign variables here without using `JSON.stringify` and getting that variable using `request.getParameter(myData)`.

What is the standard way of getting the `JSON` data into the `servlet`?

And why do people seem to be sending `Javascript objects` with JSON embedded as a String within like `data:{mydata:JSON.stringify(actualData)}`?

In case I was not being clear,I want to use the `doPost` method's `request` object to get the data I sent from the client side.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4112686/1031945

Answer (score 5):

On the server side in a servlet you can read POST data payload from request.getReader()

And you can use JSON library like [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to parse JSON. Something like:

```
YourClass obj = new Gson().fromJson(request.getReader(), YourClass.class)
```

Comment: Saved my day...Thanks ..Work like charm.!!

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
 $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:'http://localhost:8180/GisProject/MainService',
            data:{mydata:JSON.stringify(params)},
            datatype:"json",
            success:function(msg)
            { 
               console.log(msg);
            },
            error:function(xhr,status)
            {
                 console.log(status);
             }, 
        });
```

Comment: Doesnt this append the myData to the end of the url and send it as a get parameter?Also,isnt dataType for the output I get from the server?

Answer (score 0):

you can send request and response object to doGet method and than get the json in the same way.

Way to send object to doGet

doGet(request, response); call it in to the post method.

Comment: But I want to send it using `POST` and would like to parse them in `doPost`

Answer (score -1):

Hope this should help for you:

var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{ "name": "John" }' );
alert( obj.name === "John" );